# Date in Swift 3 conversion

Tags: ios, swift, date

I want this date "2016-10-18 22:06:20 +0000" to "18-10-2016", is this possible? I managed to get the date as follows:

```
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let stringDate = formatter.string(from: currentDate)
```

The above gives me "10/18/16", but how can I get "18-10-2016"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution in Swift 3

```
extension Foundation.Date {

func dashedStringFromDate() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let date = self
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  }
}
```

### Example

```
let date = Foundation.Date()
let formatedDate = date.dashedStringFromDate()
```

Answer (score 4):

Little about what you put in your question makes a lot of sense. You don't have a date as `2016-10-18 22:06:20 +0000`. The code you posted converts a current `Date` into a string. But you claim you want that string to be in the format `18-10-2016` but your code uses a completely different format.

Why not just do:

```
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let stringDate = formatter.string(from: currentDate)
```

This will convert the `currentDate` to a string in the format you mention in your question.

Comment: The problem is, I have a date, which I need in another format.

Comment: What is `currentDate`? How did you assign a value to it? Update your question with the rest of the relevant code.

Answer (score 4):

If you really have a string in the format of `2016-10-18 22:06:20 +0000` and you want to convert it to `18-10-2016`, then you want two date formatters.

The first convert that original string to a date:

```
let string = "2016-10-18 22:06:20 +0000"

let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
formatter1.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // if this string was from web service or a database, you should set the locale
formatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

guard let date = formatter1.date(from: string) else {
    fatalError("Couldn't parse original date string")
}
```

If you then want to build a new string in the format of `18-10-2016`, then you'd use a second formatter:

```
let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
formatter2.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let result = formatter2.string(from: date)
```

Comment: How to retrieve the current locale in Swift 3? I tried dateFormatter.locale = .current(), which doesn't work!! :-/

Comment: It's `dateFormatter.locale = .current`. It's a property, not a method. BTW, if you don't change the `locale`, it defaults to the current locale. The only time you change it is when you're dealing with some RFC 3339/ISO 8601 date from a web service or in a database and you want it in some consistent format, in which case you use the `en_US_POSIX` locale (see [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html)). Otherwise (e.g. if it's for showing a date in the UI), don't change the `locale` of the formatter at all, and it will default to the current locale.

Comment: Oh.. So, unlike Swift 2, we need not pick up a user's locale to format the date?

Comment: No, it's the same as Swift 2 (and Objective-C): If formatting a date for displaying to a user, don't touch the `locale` and it defaults to the current locale. When parsing RFC3339/ISO8601 dates, use `en_US_POSIX`. You only need the change the locale to `.current` if you had changed that locale to something else earlier.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks very much, Rob.. :)